# Non-blocking file read

Tags: python, python-3.x, io

How can I read the contents of a binary or a text file in a non-blocking mode?

For binary files: when I `open(filename, mode='rb')`, I get an instance of `io.BufferedReader`. The documentation fort `io.BufferedReader.read` [says](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/io.html#io.BufferedReader.read):

> Read and return size bytes, or if size is not given or negative, until EOF or if the read call would block in non-blocking mode.

Obviously a straightforward `open(filename, 'rb').read()` is in a blocking mode. To my surprise, I could not find an explanation anywhere in the `io` docs of how to choose the non-blocking mode.

For text files: when I `open(filename, mode='rt')`, I get `io.TextIOWrapper`. I assume the relevant docs are those for `read` in its base class, `io.TextIOBase`; and [according to those docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/io.html#io.TextIOBase.read), there seems no way to do non-blocking read at all:

> Read and return at most size characters from the stream as a single str. If size is negative or None, reads until EOF.

Comment: Not sure if you need to do this at a  lower level using `os.O_NONBLOCK`

Comment: please tell me why you downvoted my answer? Is it irrelevant?

Comment: @Amin Etesamian I didn't down vote and I'm not sure why someone else who read it didn't like it. It seems relevant, although I don't know aiofiles library.

Comment: @max I used it in an async file serving service. It works quite well.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

File operations are blocking. There is no non-blocking mode.

But you can create a thread which reads the file in the background. In Python 3, [`concurrent.futures` module](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/concurrent.futures.html#module-concurrent.futures) can be useful here.

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

def read_file(filename):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        return f.read()

executor = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(1)
future_file = executor.submit(read_file, 'C:\\Temp\\mocky.py')

# continue with other work

# later:

if future_file.done():
    file_contents = future_file.result()
```

Or, if you need a callback to be called when the operation is done:

```
def on_file_reading_finished(future_file):
    print(future_file.result())

future_file = executor.submit(read_file, 'C:\\Temp\\mocky.py')
future_file.add_done_callback(on_file_reading_finished)

# continue with other code while the file is loading...
```

Comment: So the reference to the non-blocking mode in the documentation applies only to non-file streams? Is there a reason why file reads cannot be non-blocking?

Comment: This solution doesn't appear to provide for any way to interrupt blocking reads to close the file, as is easy with nonblocking access. This mgiht be possible by sending a signal to the process, or maybe there is some other way to cancel a thread. I'm guessing that python file objects are designed to handle a nonblocking underlying file descriptor, which could likely be acquired via the os module.

Answer (score 13):

Python does support non-blocking reads, at least on Unix type systems, by setting the [`O_NONBLOCK` flag](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.O_NONBLOCK). In Python 3.5+, there is the [`os.set_blocking()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.set_blocking) which makes this easier:

```
import os
f = open(filename, 'rb')
os.set_blocking(f.fileno(), False)
f.read()  # This will be non-blocking.
```

However, as [zvone's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39948796) notes, this doesn't necessarily work on actual disk files. This isn't a Python thing though, but an OS limitation. As the Linux [open(2) man page](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/manpages-dev/open.2.en.html) states:

> Note that this flag has no effect for regular files and block devices;
> that is, I/O operations will (briefly) block when device activity is
> required, regardless of whether O_NONBLOCK is set.

But it does suggest this may be implemented in the future:

> Since O_NONBLOCK semantics might eventually be implemented,
> applications should not depend upon blocking behavior when specifying
> this flag for regular files and block devices.

Comment: If os.set_blocking is not available for you (python < 3.5), try ```fcntl.fcntl(f.fileno(), fcntl.F_SETFL, flag | os.O_NONBLOCK)```

Comment: Does the open() have to specify the "read binary" option (rb)?  I'm trying it without the binary option and it seems to work.

Comment: Regular files are always readable, so setting that bit does nothing, more on this post: https://www.remlab.net/op/nonblock.shtml

Answer (score 6):

I suggest using [**aiofiles**](https://github.com/Tinche/aiofiles) - a library for handling local disk files in asyncio applications.

```
import aiofiles

async def read_without_blocking():
    f = await aiofiles.open('filename', mode='r')
    try:
        contents = await f.read()
    finally:
        await f.close()
```

Comment: Not really clear what context your yield statements are suppose to go into, could you provide a more functional example?

Comment: How do I call the async function? I get an error that the function is not awaited. How do I call an async function from a sync function?

Comment: @Yankee https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55647753/call-async-function-from-sync-function-while-the-synchronous-function-continues

Comment: @Juggernaut I'm sorry that still doesn't make it clear how to use the above code. Could you please edit your code to include a sample execution

Comment: This is likely the best answer here. Any quirks one encounters can be abstracted away into a maintained library. The downside is that asyncio involves a different python coding paradigm than normal synchronous code. It takes some intro reading of the python asyncio module, to launch a run loop and write async functions to use the library. The answer might need to be updated for modern code, I'm not sure 'yield from' is still an asyncio thing, could be wrong.

Comment: Your example blocks like every ordinary file read. This is not helpful at all.