# flask + gevent pywsgi blocking on pandas and built-in io

Tags: python, pandas, flask, wsgi, gevent

Calling built-in *open()* or *pandas.read_csv()* seems to block all other requests to my flask + gevent wsgi webserver despite monkey.patch_all(). Do I need to call special gevent io functions to make them non blocking?

```
from gevent import monkey, pywsgi, sleep
monkey.patch_all()
import pandas as pd
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

FILENAME = 'c:/temp/testcsv.csv'

@app.route('/')
def fastresult():
    return 'this should return immediately'

@app.route('/non_blocking_sleep')
def non_blocking_sleep():
    sleep(10)
    return 'using gevent.sleep does NOT block other reqeusts as expected'

@app.route('/readcsv')
def readcsv(): 
    """
    this blocks any other request before the read completes
    """
    df = pd.read_csv(FILENAME)
    return df.info()


@app.route('/openfile')
def openfile():
    """
    this blocks any other request before the read completes
    """
    with open(FILENAME, 'r') as file:
        res = file.readlines()
    return res[:1000]

http_server = pywsgi.WSGIServer(('', 5000), app)
http_server.serve_forever()
```

Tested on Anaconda 5.3 (python 3.7) 64 bit on both Windows and Linux.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Non-blocking file read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39948588/non-blocking-file-read)

Comment: no, this question is specific to gevent instead of regular python blocking io

Comment: Was there any progress regarding the question?