# Call async function from sync function, while the synchronous function continues : Python

Tags: python-3.x, asynchronous, python-asyncio

After perusing many docs on `AsyncIO` and articles I still could not find an answer to this : ***Run a function asynchronously (without using a thread) and also ensure the function calling this async function continues its execution.***

**Pseudo - code :**

```
async def functionAsync(p):
    #...
    #perform intensive calculations
    #...
    print ("Async loop done")

def functionNormal():
    p = ""
    functionAsync(p)
    return ("Main loop ended")

 print ("Start Code")
 print functionNormal()
```

Expected Output :

```
Start code
Main loop ended
Async loop done
```

Searched examples where `loop.run_until_complete` is used, but that will not return the print value of `functionNormal()` as it is blocking in nature.

Comment: If it should run "without using a thread", how do you expect this to work? Or, are you saying that it's ok for the _implementation_ to use threads under the hood, but you don't want to create a thread explicitly?

Comment: Yes that is what I mean. Explicitly I do not want to create a thread. If it does it under the hood it's fine (which acc to my knowledge it might not be, as per my reading concurrency does not always mean a new thread.)

Comment: Concurrency doesn't always mean a new thread **if** you use coroutines (`async def`) for all your code. But your requirement is to have a sync function executed concurrently with async code, and that will certainly require multiple threads or fibers.

Comment: Async code can be started in a new event loop too if i'm correct. loop = `asyncio.new_event_loop()` ..And yes you are right, the sync code should continue running and go to the next line of code as shown in the example.

Comment: `new_event_loop` only allocates an event loop. To actually run async code in it, you must use `run_until_complete` or `run_forever`, which blocks the current thread - so you need an additional thread to run sync code concurrently with async code. It will never work without threads.

Comment: I need to use context locals of `request.args` from flask . This is why I did not want to create a new thread.

Answer (score 20):

Just use `asyncio.run()` inside a synchronous function.

```
def syncfunc():
    async def asyncfunc():
        await some_async_work()
    asyncio.run(asyncfunc())

syncfunc()
```

Note that asyncio.run() cannot be called when another asyncio event loop is running in the same thread.

Comment: How to do while another loop is running?

Comment: This is blocking. Can you please provide an example the reproduces the required output?

Answer (score 14):

`asyncio` can't run arbitrary code "in background" without using threads. As **user4815162342** noted, in `asyncio` you run event loop that blocks main thread and manages execution of coroutines.

If you want to use `asyncio` and take advantage of using it, you should rewrite all your functions that uses coroutines to be coroutines either up to main function - entry point of your program. This main coroutine is usually passed to `run_until_complete`. This [little post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33399896/1113207) reveals this topic in more detail.

---

Since you're interested in Flask, take a look [Quart](https://github.com/pgjones/quart#quart): it's a web framework that tries to implement Flask API (as much as it's possible) in terms of `asyncio`. Reason this project exists is because pure Flask isn't compatible with `asyncio`. Quart is written to be compatible.

If you want to stay with pure Flask, but have asynchronous stuff, take a look at [gevent](http://www.gevent.org/). Through monkey-patching it can make your code asynchronous. Although this solution has its own problems (which why `asyncio` was created).

Comment: `asyncio.ensure_future(my_coro(param1, param2))` works when inside a sync function (like a callback) with a running event loop.

Answer (score 12):

Maybe it's a bit late, but I'm running into a similar situation and I solved it in Flask by using run_in_executor:

```
def work(p):
    # intensive work being done in the background


def endpoint():
    p = ""
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_in_executor(None, work, p)
```

I'm not sure however how safe this is since the loop is not being closed.

Answer (score 9):

Here's a helper function to synchronize an async operation:

```py
import asyncio
import time

async def sleep_return(s):
    time.sleep(s)
    return 420

def async_to_sync(awaitable):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    return loop.run_until_complete(awaitable)

async_result = async_to_sync(sleep_return(.69))
print(f"Result from async call: { async_result }")

# Output:
# Result from async call: 420
```

You can inline most of the calls to the asyncio api to simplify it even more, but this is a little bit cleaner, imho

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the synchronous function is inside an asynchronous function, you can solve it using exceptions.
Pseudo code:

```
class CustomError(Exception):
pass


async def main():
    def test_syn():
        time.sleep(2)
        # Start Async
        raise CustomError
    try:
        test_syn()
    except CustomError:
        await asyncio.sleep(2)
```