# How to deal with 'await' outside async function?

Tags: python, async-await, fastapi

The below function is calling the create_presigned_url but I am getting an error in await.

```
 def getPreSignedURL(request: Request, file: UploadFile = File(...) ):
       resp = await create_presigned_url(request,file)
       return resp
```

this is an async function which I want to call

```
async def create_presigned_url(bucket_name, object_name, expiration=3600):
---
return response
```

Comment: Please provide the error.

Comment: you can not call an async method from a sync method. for more info https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55647753/call-async-function-from-sync-function-while-the-synchronous-function-continues

Comment: You cannot call an async function from the regular function as described above.  You would need to use asyncio.

Comment: @tomarv where to use this asyncio?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hope this helps. Example of calling async function from regular function:

```
import asyncio

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()


async def demo(name):
    return f"hello {name}"


def main():
    result = loop.run_until_complete(demo("world"))
    print(result)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Yes, I did it, I was missing async before function declaration, that has resolved the issue. Thanks for helping

Comment: @sakshisinghal If you agree with the answer do you mind up voting it.